# Loading flat data into a tree data structure

Tags: c#, recursion, tree, parent-child, treenode

Currently, I have an Item class and a list of items representing flat data retrieved from a SQL Server 2012 DB query. Here is the Item class.

```
public class Item
{
    public string Parent { get; set; }
    public string Child { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

I need to transform this flat data into a tree structure and have the ability to traverse the tree while performing some action. Here is a visual of some data. My tree will always have a single root node.

[image: Tree Data and Structure]

I have seen several posts on SO pertaining to this but I'm still struggling with it. Here is the generic TreeNode class I have.

```
public class TreeNode<T>
{
    private readonly T _value;
    private readonly List<TreeNode<T>> _children = new List<TreeNode<T>>();

    public TreeNode(T value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public TreeNode<T> this[int i]
    {
        get { return _children[i]; }
    }

    public TreeNode<T> Parent { get; private set; }

    public T Value { get { return _value; } }

    public ReadOnlyCollection<TreeNode<T>> Children
    {
        get { return _children.AsReadOnly(); }
    }

    public TreeNode<T> AddChild(T value)
    {
        var node = new TreeNode<T>(value) { Parent = this };
        _children.Add(node);
        return node;
    }

    public TreeNode<T>[] AddChildren(params T[] values)
    {
        return values.Select(AddChild).ToArray();
    }

    public bool RemoveChild(TreeNode<T> node)
    {
        return _children.Remove(node);
    }

    public void Traverse(Action<T> action)
    {
        action(Value);
        foreach (var child in _children)
            child.Traverse(action);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Flatten()
    {
        return new[] { Value }.Concat(_children.SelectMany(x => x.Flatten()));
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble recursively loading the flat data into the tree structure. I also don't understand how to utilize the Action inside the Traverse method to perform some task while traversing. To populate the tree, I believe I need to start with the root. I obtain it like this:

```
var root = new TreeNode<Item>(items.Single(i => i.Parent == null));
```

I can then load the first level down like so:

```
root.AddChildren(items.Where(i => i.Parent.Equals(root.Value.Child)).ToArray());
```

My two questions are as follows:

1. How can I recursively load everything?
2. How do I use the Action inside the Traverse method to simply write out the tree structure by item names with proper indentation (or perform any task for that matter)?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: One question per post, please. If someone answers the first question correctly, and the second wrong, and another one answers the first wrong but the second correctly, how would you choose what answer to accept?

Comment: I would change the name of your class from Item to Node which is normally used.   Your Node has child defined wrong : public string Child { get; set; }.  It should be public List<Node> Child { get; set; }or in the case of a binary tree have public Node Left { get; set; } and public Node Right { get; set; }

Comment: @jdweng - No, Item actually represents a part in our SQL database's bill of materials table and that class cannot change. There is a recursive CTE that spits out the flat list of items, which represent a BOM. I need to transform the flat list of items to an IEnumberable of TreeNodes. The flat Item in the list doesn't have a collection of children. I'm trying to map the flat item to nodes that have children (and a parent). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First question: recursive loading**

You need to create a helper function (if you code in C# 7.0 you can do that as a local function and strip the `items` parameter):

```
private static void AddDescendants(IReadOnlyCollection<Item> items, TreeNode<Item> node)
{
    var children = node.AddChildren(items.Where(i => i.Parent == node.Value.Child).ToArray());
    foreach (var child in children)
    {
        AddDescendants(items, child);
    }
}
```

Calling it, as per your example after obtaining root:

```
var root = new TreeNode<Item>(items.Single(i => i.Parent == null));
AddDescendants(items, root);
```

**Second question: Traversal**

Your `Traverse` function does [pre-order traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order) and provides absolutely no information whatsoever on which tree level you are, and so cannot be used to perform indentation in output.

If you change the implementation to take `Action<TreeNode<T>>` like so:

```
public void Traverse(Action<TreeNode<T>> action)
{
    action(this);
    foreach (var child in _children)
        child.Traverse(action);
}
```

Then you can calculate indentation level by counting parents:

```
root.Traverse(node =>
{
    var depth = 0;
    var ancestor = node.Parent;
    while (ancestor != null)
    {
        depth++;
        ancestor = ancestor.Parent;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(new string(' ', depth * 2) + node.Value.Name);
});
```

Here's a full working sample with output: https://ideone.com/faVOtd

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate the effort and full working sample.

Comment: if I add a property IsRoot on the TreeNode how can I access it inside the action?

Comment: If you use original Traverse function, you won't be able to. In my suggested implementation, the parameter is the TreeNode, so [you can access IsRoot] directly from the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it is normally done in classes

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication23
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("_InvTrans");
            dt.Columns.Add("Parent", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Child", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Null", "A", "Alpha" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "A", "B", "Bravo" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "A", "C", "Charlie" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "B", "E", "Echo" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "B", "F", "Foxtrot" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "C", "W", "Whiskey" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "C", "H", "Hotel" });

            new Node(dt);

        }

    }
    public class Node
    {
        public static Node root = new Node();
        static DataTable dt = null;

        public List<Node> Child { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }

        public Node(){}
        public Node(DataTable dt)
        {
            Node.dt = dt;
            root.id = "Null";
            Add(root);
        }

        public static void Add(Node parent)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in Node.dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("Parent") == parent.id))
            {
                Node child = new Node();
                if (parent.Child == null) parent.Child = new List<Node>();
                parent.Child.Add(child);
                child.Name = row.Field<string>("Name");
                child.id = row.Field<string>("Child");
                Add(child);
            }
        }
    }

}
```